# Facebook - Debugger Whitelist

Tags: facebook, debugging

I want to whitelist only the [Facebook Debugger Tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/) so it can see our development environments and I am wondering how I am able to do that? I see that Facebook has provided a list [IPs and User Agents](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/howtos/maximizing-distribution-media-content/#crawl) to whitelist but I believe this will whitelist ALL of Facebook instead of just their debugger tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is correct, there's no more specific information available about which IPs within Facebook's datacenters will be used for the debugger, you need to whitelist all IPs under AS32934

I don't really understand why that's something you don't want to do, the only traffic you should receive *directly* from Facebook is from the debugger, other automated systems (e.g. Advertising review) or Facebook employees (e.g. if you submit your app for app center or open graph approvals and it needs to be reviewed)

Comment: I don't want someone on our QA team to accidentally 'Like' one of our products and somehow accidentally leak information to the public.

Comment: That doesn't really apply here - if the crawler can reach the URL, anyone can theoretically like that URL and have hte metadata appear in the story on their profile - the request made from an abitrary user liking the page is the same as when you check the URL in thedebugger
There's no way to make requests from the crawler when it's triggered from teh debugger be treated differently than when triggered because of a like button - it's the same process